# How to keep web content below the users view?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

This is a strange question but, is there a way to keep a block of content below the view of the page no matter what size the page is?

I've seen it where parallax scrolling kind of does that but it's more code than I need. I don't plan on having any foreground / background scrolling effects.

Just want a title page that will show and a call to action button that will scroll down to content with no unnecessary amount of margin/padding that would skew the flow on a mobile device.

[image: Example of view on desktop and mobile]

Example of almost working product http://www.keisha.in/testing

```
/*Section 1 */
#portfolio {
    margin-top: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

/*Section 2 */
#resume {
    margin-top: 200%;
    position: absolute;
}

<div id="title"> Title Page  <a href="#portfolio">Work</a> </div>


<div id="portfolio"> Stuff </div>

<div id="resume"> Other Stuff </div>
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.**

Comment: Search about `position:fixed` ?

Comment: I edited the post. The problem I run into using position fixed is that it sits on top of all the content.

Comment: It's almost like a splash page with out being a separate page. You would see for example my name and what I do, to see my portfolio or my resume click a link and it will scroll down to it.

Comment: Position fixed won't help. So basically you need the content above to be at least the height of the window.

Comment: Ok I edited the question with updated code and put an example of the almost working page in there as well. The only concern I have now is the huge amount of whitespace. I wonder if there's a more dynamic way of keeping content below view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very sure that I understand your question but this is maybe a rough variant of what you are looking for - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E42UY/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-content">
    <a href="#bottom_content">Read theText...</a>
</div>

<div class="bottom-content" id="bottom_content">
    blah...blah...blah...blah...blah...
    blah...blah...blah...blah...blah...
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main-content,
.bottom-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.main-content {
    background: red;
}
.bottom-content {
    margin-top: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

For additional help - share with us your example code.

Comment: NoSense, this is perfection. I have 3 sections I need to do this to, I'm hoping with different percentages I will be able to achieve the look I'm going for.

Comment: Also is there a better way I could have worded my question?

Comment: @kayhart - yes, for 2nd section add margin-top: 200%, for the 3th - 300% and so on :).

Comment: So I uploaded it to github so you could see the results http://www.keisha.in/testing Things are a bit wonkey with layout but I think I'm getting it. Only concern is the huge amount of whitespace between the sections.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I think that you have these huge white spaces because: 1) You maybe didn't reset some basics CSSs - http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/; 2) In you site(btw very cool :)) some sections doesn't have 100% height and for example you tried to center the first section by adding margin-top, but if you want the logo and the button to be always centered you have to wrap them in another div and do something like on this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/E42UY/6/

Comment: No it's fine! I'm just glad you answered. That worked! Putting the 100% on each section. I had the resets in there already and I implemented your method to centering that title div. Thank you so much, for your help and the compliment.

Comment: Final result http://www.keisha.in/ Thanks again :D  @NoSense

Answer (score 0):

I believe (with information you provided), you need to give the bottom-content div the following css styles

```
#bottom-content{
  position:fixed;
  height:100px; /*just for an example*/
  width:100%; /* your image looked like it needed 100% */
  bottom:-105px; /*-(heightOfElement) and extra five pixels, just to be safe */
}
```

meanwhile I type this answer, @Danko said it.. Thanks @Danko..

Guess it helps.

As @NoSense pointed out, in such cases, I would rather ask you to

```
display : none;
```

initially and then

```
display: block;
```

with javascript/jquery onClick

Comment: When you add negative bottom value to fixed position element this will hide it and I think you can't see it just with anchor pointed to it...or maybe I'm in а mistake...

Comment: I agree @NoSense :-) .. Would need a bit of javascript/jquery to change its position and scroll to it. I was suggesting an answer to hide the div. Thanks anyway..

Comment: Hmm.. I wonder if this method could work in junction with the smooth scrolling jquery. My only concern is that if the user doesn't click the button and they scroll down the information will still be hidden.